# In Call of Duty Elite, what does SPM mean?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-elite

In the Call of Duty Elite service, on the Connect tab, it is possible to sort the members of your clan by different stats.  One of them is "SPM", which is presumably a X per minute stat.  What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be referring to "[score per minute](http://www.iplaycod.com/forums/4-general-discussion/16750-elite-clan-spm.cod)" - a measure of how many points you are gaining per unit time.